# Push plot legend up slightly in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have an ECDF plot I've created with R and it has a legend in the bottom right hand corner.  The problem I'm having is that the faint grey dashed horizontal line that the ECDF plot places at 0.0 is overlapping the last item in my legend.  Like so:

[image]

At the moment I'm creating the legend with:

```
legend("bottomright",c("Original","Minus 30 minutes"),col=c("black","red"),lty=c("dashed","dotted"))
```

Is there a way to simply push the legend up a little to avoid the overlap problem?  An ideal solution would be one that programatically detects the overlap and corrects for it appropriately, but failing this, some empirically determined number of pixels offset would probably suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to use `inset=c(0,.01)` (or some other value) in your call to legend

Comment: .05 or greater for the `y` coordinate of the `inset` would probably be more appropriate, but this is the right idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
legend(x=1e+04, y=0.2, c("Original","Minus 30 minutes"), 
                       col=c("black","red"), 
                       lty=c("dashed","dotted"))
```

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, the `legend` function also has a neat `trace=` option which you can use for recording the exact specifications of how the legend was created. You can save this data to an object and use it for making corrections to the auto-formatted legend. It might be overkill for your current scenario, but it is quite a neat little system.

E.g.:

```
# plot a test plot
> plot(1:10)

# calculate the details for a legend in the bottomright, save the data
# and don't add the legend itself
> legdata <- legend("bottomright","boom",trace=TRUE,plot=FALSE)

> legdata
$rect
$rect$w
[1] 1.454288

$rect$h
[1] 1.65623

$rect$left
[1] 8.905712

$rect$top
[1] 2.29623


$text
$text$x
[1] 9.456811

$text$y
[1] 1.468115

# re-use the saved legend data to push the legend up slightly
> legend(list(x=legdata$rect$left,y=legdata$rect$top+0.5),"boom")
```